# How to build and use Sigar for C/C++?

Tags: c, sigar

Since there are no instructions on their wiki or Github, this is what I tried:

1. Cloned [the git repository](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar)
2. `make`
3. To run `examples/cpuinfo.c`:

`cd examples/`

`gcc -Wall -I../include -L../build-src -lsigar cpuinfo.c`

It gives me:

```
cpuinfo.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `sigar_open'
cpuinfo.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `sigar_cpu_list_get'
cpuinfo.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `sigar_strerror'
cpuinfo.c:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `sigar_cpu_list_destroy'
cpuinfo.c:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `sigar_close'
```

What do I have to link it with to resolve these errors?

Comment: I believe this to be somewhat off-topic. That said, there's a `Makefile.am` in the `examples/` directory, too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `-lsigar` to the end of the list, after cpuinfo.c